# How to rewrite url for any specific taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have custom post registered it's archive has url **`example.com/doctors`**

It's Single post has url **`example.com/doctors/john-cardiff`**

It has categories as well, for example for ***cardiology*** category currently url is

```
example.com/specialty/cardiology
```

I want to make it `example.com/cardiology/doctors` for category

Please help me to re-write the url.

I found this code but i have no idea how to use it?

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'with_front' => false,
    'slug' => 'product/poruct-cats',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the correct code. Just replace it in register taxonomy function (you may find mention function in functions.php) at a 'rewrite': true with your code.

Comment: Please help me get the url i mentioned my question by posting the code.